# Как с помощью !рекурсивной функции! определить количество строчных латинских букв. Си

Tags: c, строки, рекурсия

Само условие:
"**С клавиатуры вводится последовательность символов (текст), заканчивающаяся
точкой. Используя рекурсивную функцию подсчитать количество строчных латинских букв, встречающихся в тексте.**"
Не особо понимаю как это реализовать с помощью рекурсии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да сколько угодно :) Например:

```
int count_lower(const char * s)
{
    if (*s == '.') return 0;

    return (islower(*s) ? 1 : 0) + count_lower(s+1);
}
```

Устраивает?

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот сейчас разобрал и оказалась настолько простой программа в реализации, что аж стыдно стало за такой вопрос.
Надеюсь кому-то поможет он.

Comment: Зато такие вещи - через сильные эмоции - понимаются и запоминаются надолго...